# mongodb connection failed after assigning IP to new server

Tags: mongodb

We have mongodb running and everything is fine with it. I can connect to it from my kubernetes cluster and from my PC. I created new kubernetes cluster, assigned IP addresses from old cluster machines to new nodes and i'm not able to connect from those new nodes. Application and settings are the same.
When i try manually connect to mongodb then:

```
mongo mongodb://correct-username:correct-password@correct-IP
.......
Error: Authentication failed.
```

When i assign those IP's back to old cluster nodes then i'm able to connect again.
Only thing that has been changed is MAC address and OS. IP addresses are the same. Is there somekind of "connection cache". Differect MAC but same IP causing problems? I'm quite new with mongodb.

Comment: Does the database in the new machine have the same content as the old one? Because normally the username and password are saved in the "admin" database/collection. If it isn't there.. then we can't authenticate.

Comment: Database is on another VM, no changes there.

Comment: The bounty isn't going to do much given the information you posted.

Comment: @Jaur try what Dang has mentioned, post your proper connection string first up. Now use the `authenticationDatabase=admin` option, as in general, unless you changed that is where it is stored. 

And paste more content from the shell, when you get authentication error.

Answer (score 2):

Authentication happens after a successful connection. Therefore, if you are receiving an authentication error, the connection succeeded.

Since authentication is orthogonal to IP addresses, you misconfigured something during your move.

Comment: I just assigned IP address to new node. Container application setup is 100% same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Atlas instance or self-hosted MongoDB Server?

Maybe your current setup has [IP Access List](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security/ip-access-list/) (whitelist of IP addresses) configured, and when you try to connect from somewhere which is not in that list, you will not be authenticated. You should check that, and if that is the problem, just add new IP addresses on the list.

Comment: Self hosted server(s). As mentioned before, IP is assigned from one node to another. So, no FW problems etc. I can actually terlnet mongodb port and it's answering.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a mongodb replicaSet , standalone or sharded cluster, how rs.conf() looks like? If you configure the rs based on old ip-addresses this explain the issue... , you will need to rs.reconfig() and change to the new IPs...